# VS регулярно вылетает

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

Поставил VS Express 2013 Update 5, по кабелю подключил Lumia 640.
При работе с конструктором столкнулся с проблемой, что студия переходит в режим "не отвечает" при попытке добавить элемент.
После краща элемент на месте. С чем это может быть связано? Как лечить?

Comment: характеристики пк в студию. и почему не нормальная 15 студия?

Comment: Баги в стороннем софте вроде не онтопик у нас?

Comment: Раз не формат борда, то удалю вопрос.

Comment: В чате совместно решили, что всё-таки онтопик :)

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron: Извините, ввёл вас в заблуждение. Таки-онтопик.